# Collect all jar libraries

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven Java project in my Eclipse that runs on Windows 10. The project builds fine and generates m-m.jar file in the target folder.

How to ask Maven to collect all required jar's that are needed to run this project?

pom.xml content:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mini</groupId>
  <artifactId>m</artifactId>
  <version>m</version>
  
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies> 
  
</project>
```

Comment: What do you mean, this JAR should already contain all dependencies?

Comment: I need collection of all required jar files in one place. I will need them for installation purposes.

Comment: No need put evrything in one jar

Comment: What does "collection of all required JAR files" mean? This is too vague ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dependency:copy-dependencies` to copy all dependencies to one place.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

If you want to build a standalone Java application, you can also use the assembly or shade plugin to put all dependencies into the resulting JAR itself.